# Access Microsoft CRM Imports using SDK

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

How can I access information about Imports (which you can access via Workplace => Imports, see picture), using SDK? Partucularly I'm interested in a list of errors associated with each Import entry. Even a hint at which classes I should look/check would also be great.

[image: Microsoft CRM 2011 Imports]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main entity is `ImportFile`, you can check the structure here:

[MSDN - ImportFile Entity Metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309352.aspx)

you can check the fields `totalcount` `successcount` `failurecount` `partialfailurecount`

the errors are inside the entity `ImportLog`, you can check the structure here:

[MSDN - ImportLog Entity Metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328518.aspx)

you can check the fields `importfileid` (the lookup that contains the relationship with `importfile`) `linenumber` `errornumber`

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies things a bit. Can you please tell to which entity maps `importdataid` attribute of the `importlog` entities?

Comment: Oh, found it, that's `importdata` (duh!). But still can't find that entity desc in MSDN docs.. Anyway thanks, I guess I can figure out rest of things by myself.